# How to show border in multicolumn and multirow cells for table?

Tags: tables, multicol, multicolumn, border

I am using the code,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Dataset} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{A} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} \\
    & O.B.R & A.R & O.B.R & A.R & O.B.R & A.R \\
    \hline
    D1 & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% \\
    \hline
    D2 & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% \\
    \hline
    D3 & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Which producing below output,
[image]

**Now how can I show border around header A, B, C?**

Comment: ` \multicolumn{2}{c|}{A} \multicolumn{2}{c|}{B}` will do it. Do you also want a horizontal line?

Comment: @Bernard yes both horizontal and vertical border for all cells

Comment: Depending on the data, it might also be worthwhile to transpose the table and possibly split this into AR and OBR tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than work with a visually unappealing and oldfashioned-looking table design with lots and lots of vertical and horizontal lines, I'd work with a far more open design, or "look", that features (a) no vertical lines at all and (b) fewer, but well-spaced horizontal lines. To achieve this look, it helps to load the `booktabs` package and employ its macros `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\cmidrule`, and `\bottomrule`.

The following screenshot compare and contrast the "closed" ("prison window") and "open" looks with a pair of "Before" and "After" tables. (The "before" table fixes the formatting issue you identified in your query and also supplies a `\cline` directive.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Before\strut}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Dataset} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{A} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{B} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} \\
      \cline{2-7}
    & O.B.R & A.R & O.B.R & A.R & O.B.R & A.R \\
    \hline
    D1 & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% \\
    \hline
    D2 & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% \\
    \hline
    D3 & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\caption{After\strut}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{6}{r} @{}}
  \toprule
  Dataset &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{A} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{C} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7}
  & O.B.R & A.R & O.B.R & A.R & O.B.R & A.R \\
  \midrule
  D1 & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% \\
  D2 & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% \\
  D3 & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question about allowing line-breaking in the header cells: There are several ways to accomplish this objective. The easiest one I can think of is to employ a `tabularx` environment and to use (a centered version of) the `X` column type for the 6 header cells. For the data cells, I would recommend alignment on the decimal markers. This, in turn, may be achieved with the `dcolumn` package and its `D` column type. Of course, I'd still go with an open and inviting "look".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}     % align numbers on decimal markers
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X} % centered version of 'X' col. type
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Line-breaking allowed in header cells\strut}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{6}{d{2.2}} @{}}
  \toprule
  Dataset &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{C} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7}
  & \mC{O.B.R} & \mC{A.R} & \mC{O.B.R} & \mC{A.R} 
  & \mC{O.B.R} & \multicolumn{1}{C@{}}{A.R} \\
  \midrule
  D1 & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% \\
  D2 & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% \\
  D3 & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is it possible to update the solution which will support line break in titles?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan - Please provide more information about your formatting needs. E.g., might you need automatic line breaking in all header cells, or just in 1 or 2?

Comment: I want manual line breaking i.e. with `\\`. Or you can also discuss other options as well.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan - Please see the addendum I posted just now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with some improvements: numbers are aligned on the decimal dot with the `S`column type, from `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\sisetup{table-format=2.1, table-space-text-post= \%}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|*{6}{S|}}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Dataset} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{A} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{B} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} \\
\cline{2-7}
   & {O.B.R} & {A.R} & {O.B.R} & {A.R} & {O.B.R} & {A.R} \\
    \hline
    D1 & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% \\
    \hline
    D2 & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% \\
    \hline
    D3 & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to update the solution which will support line break in titles?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? This is not really clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

In `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have a key `hvlines` to draw all the rules excepted in the blocks... and the blocks (rectangles of merged cells) are created with the command `\Block` (both horizontally and vertically).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{c*{6}{r}}[hvlines]
    \Block{2-1}{Dataset} &
      \Block{1-2}{A} & &
      \Block{1-2}{B} & & 
      \Block{1-2}{C} \\
   & {O.B.R} & \Block[c]{1-1}{A.R} & {O.B.R} & \Block[c]{1-1}{A.R} & {O.B.R} & \Block[c]{1-1}{A.R} \\
    D1 & 2.1 \%& 2.1 \%& 2.1 \%& 2.1 \%& 2.1 \%& 2.1 \%\\
    D2 & 11.6 \%& 11.6 \%& 11.6 \%& 11.6 \%& 11.6 \%& 11.6 \%\\
    D3 & 5.5 \%& 5.5 \%& 5.5 \%& 5.5 \%& 5.5 \%& 5.5 \%\\
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]