# How to get the titles broken into multiple lines for multicolumn and multirow?

Tags: tables, line-breaking, multicolumn, multirow

I am using below code,

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Before\strut}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
      \multirow{2}{*}{Ser.} &
      \multirow{2}{*}{$V_{tune}$ (V)} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Frequency (GHz)} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Power Consumption (mW)} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Phase Noise at 1MHz (dBc/Hz)} \\
      \cline{3-8}
    && Schematic & Post-layout & Schematic & Post-layout & Schematic & Post-layout\\
    \hline
    a1 & D1 & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% \\
    \hline
    a1 & D2 & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% \\
    \hline
    a1 & D3 & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Output
[image]

The content is going beyond my page ma**rgin. I want the titles broken into multiple lines. How can I do so?**

Answer (score 4):

If you load `geometry` to have more decent margins than the default, and use `makecell`, it can fit between the margins. With the default layout, you can reduce the value of `\tabcolsep` (6pt by default, that you can reduce to 3pt without problem) and the font size (setting the table to `\small`, for instance).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{multirow, makecell, caption}
\captionsetup{skip =4pt }
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\dBc}{dBc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\caption{Before}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|*{6}{S|}}
    \hline
      \multirow{2.5}{*}{Ser.} &
      \multirowcell{2.5}{$V_\text{tune}$\\ (V)} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Frequency (GHz)} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\makecell{Power Consumption\\ (\si{\mW})}} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\makecell{Phase Noise at \SI{1}{\MHz} \\(\si{dBc\per\Hz})}} \\
      \cline{3-8}
    && {Schematic} & {Post-layout} & {Schematic} & {Post-layout} & {Schematic} & {Post-layout}\\
    \hline
    a1 & D1 & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% \\
    \hline
    a1 & D2 & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% \\
    \hline
    a1 & D3 & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here are two versions of your table. In both I have used the `\thead` command from the `makecell` package in order to introduce linebreaks in the table headers. Additionally, I have used `siunitx` for the units in the headers as well as to improve the alignment of the numbers in the table. I have also included a version without vertical lines and less horizontal lines fro a more open look of your table. Please be aware that both tables are still wider than the textwidth of a regula `article` class. Sonce no documentclass was given in your example, I did not address that issue here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Before with thead from the makecell package and siunitx}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|*{6}{S[table-format=2.1, table-space-text-post=\%]|}}
    \hline
      \thead{Ser.} &
      \thead{$V_{tune}$\\ (\si{\volt})} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{Frequency\\ (\si{\giga\hertz})}} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{Power Consumption\\ (\si{\milli\watt})}} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{Phase Noise at\\ \SI{1}{\mega\hertz} (\si{dBc\per\hertz})}} \\
      \cline{3-8}
    && {Schematic} & {Post-layout} & {Schematic} & {Post-layout} & {Schematic} & {Post-layout}\\
    \hline
    a1 & D1 & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% \\
    \hline
    a1 & D2 & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% \\
    \hline
    a1 & D3 & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Before with thead from the makecell package, siunitx and booktabs}
\begin{tabular}{cc*{6}{S[table-format=2.1, table-space-text-post=\%]}}
    \toprule
      \thead{Ser.} &
      \thead{$V_{tune}$\\ (\si{\volt})} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Frequency\\ (\si{\giga\hertz})}} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Power Consumption\\ (\si{\milli\watt})}} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Phase Noise at\\ \SI{1}{\mega\hertz} (\si{dBc\per\hertz})}} \\
      \cmidrule(r){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(l){7-8}
    && {Schematic} & {Post-layout} & {Schematic} & {Post-layout} & {Schematic} & {Post-layout}\\
    \midrule
    a1 & D1 & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% \\
    a1 & D2 & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% \\
    a1 & D3 & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The table can easily fit into the textwidth of `article` if you use

```
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cc*{6}{S[table-format=2.1, table-space-text-post=\%]}}
```

instead.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version of the table from my [earlier answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553566/5001) that's adapted to your new table. It uses a `tabularx` environment to allow line-breaking in the header cells. It also performs alignment of the numbers on their decimal markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e,dcolumn}'
% To align numbers on decimal markers:
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}  
% Centered version of 'X' column type:
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X}
% Allow line-breaking across two-wide cells
\newcolumntype{E}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep\relax}C}
% Handy shortcut macro:
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}} 
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\centering
\caption{Table with automatic line breaks in header cells\strut}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lc *{6}{d{2.2}} @{}}
\toprule
Ser. &
\mytab{$V_{\mathrm{tune}}$ \\ (V)} &
\multicolumn{2}{E}{Frequency (GHz)} &
\multicolumn{2}{E}{Power Consumption (mW)} &
\multicolumn{2}{E@{}}{Phase Noise at 1\,MHz (dBc/Hz)} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(l){7-8} 
&& \mC{Schematic} & \mC{Post-layout} 
 & \mC{Schematic} & \mC{Post-layout} 
 & \mC{Schematic} & \mC{Post-layout} \\
\midrule
 a1 & D1 & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% \\
 a1 & D2 & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% \\
 a1 & D3 & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```